# SNS subscription error for AmazonIpSpaceChanged on different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

Why is it that I can't susbscribe SNS on AmazonIpSpaceChanged? Please check, I need your guidance.

The guide I basically followed with is [How to Automatically Update Your Security Groups for Amazon CloudFront and AWS WAF by Using AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-automatically-update-your-security-groups-for-amazon-cloudfront-and-aws-waf-by-using-aws-lambda/) from the AWS Security blog.

Here's an output of the terminal:

```
➜  terminal $ cat ~/.aws/config
[default]
region = ap-southeast-1
➜  terminal $ aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged --protocol lambda --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:accountid_removed:function:cloudfront-securitygroup-controller

An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Subscribe operation: Invalid parameter: TopicArn
➜  terminal $ AWS_REGION=ap-southeast-1 aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged --protocol lambda --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:accountid_removed:function:cloudfront-securitygroup-controller

An error occurred (AuthorizationError) when calling the Subscribe operation: User: arn:aws:iam::accountid_removed:user/removed@gmail.com is not authorized to perform: SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged
```

This is also the output when done through the AWS Web Console:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::accountid_removed:user/removed@gmail.com is not authorized to perform: SNS:Subscribe on resource: arn:aws:sns:ap-southeast-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AuthorizationError; Request ID: 0e87384a-e298-569e-bf2d-6a5718eedc40)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is because your API call must be made to the `us-east-1` region, where the Amazon SNS topic is located.

```
$ aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged --protocol email --notification-endpoint xyzzy@mailinator.com --region us-east-1
{
    "SubscriptionArn": "pending confirmation"
}
```

It appears that subscribe a AWS Lambda function in a different region works too (or, at least did not return an error):

```
aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged --protocol lambda --notification-endpoint arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:foo --region us-east-1
{
    "SubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged:37dab281-1e8f-16ba-8e4a-ef9de429101b"
}
```

Comment: Last time I tested it out with `AWS_REGION=us-east-1` and it failed.

It's a good thing you pointed it out that I need to use the `--region` parameter, and it works.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This is also possible from CloudFormation, with the (new) Region parameter.

Code snipped of CloudFormation (json) SNS resource:

```
"LambdaAmazonIpSpaceChangedSubscription" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::SNS::Subscription",
  "Properties" : {
    "Endpoint" : {"Fn::GetAtt" : ["LambdaFunction", "Arn"] },
    "Protocol" : "lambda",
    "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged",

    "Region": "us-east-1"

  }
},
```